# How to exit fullscreen in android chrome?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, chrome-for-android

I've added one of my regular news websites to my homescreen in android chrome (android 4.4, phone). This works great, it now even opens the site fullscreen to give an 'app experience'.

How can I exit this fullscreen mode? For instance so I get access to the menu so I can share articles.

The 'add to home screen' feature is described [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/installtohomescreen)

Comment: Is this on a tablet (and not a phone)?

Comment: This is on a phone (nexus 5)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the fullscreen mode. But I've played around around with Chrome on my S4, and it goes into fullscreen mode if I scroll to the bottom of page (the address bar disappears). If I scroll to the top, it shows the address bar again. To exit, I just quit as usual, by pressing the back button key on my phone. Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: I've made the title more clear so it reflects the question. It is about exiting full screen, not exiting the app.

Comment: The fullscreen is just a matter of scrolling to top or to bottom. This is the way Chrome for Android implements "fullscreen". Have you observed the behavior?

Comment: The behavior is different when starting a site from a link from the homescreen, the scrolling up doesn't show anything, the browser actually starts in a different mode or something.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55659/how-do-i-disable-full-screen-mode-in-chrome-for-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can. The site is supporting the mobile-web-app-capable view which means Chrome displays it like an app, hides the address bar and it integrates into the recent apps menu as though it was a 'normal' app.
I don't believe there is a way to exit fullscreen when using a bookmark to a site like this.

For those who are unsure what the OP is referring to, http://weight.aerotwist.com/ is a site that supports this 'app' mode. If you browse to the site in Chrome and chose the menu option "Add to home screen" this adds a 'bookmark' to your home screen which when used launches the site in Chrome in app mode.

See [here](http://googlesystem.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/add-shortcuts-to-web-apps-in-chrome-for.html) for more details.